# In Apached Airflow Airflow 1.10.12 -No module named 'httplib2'

Tags: airflow

I am getting the below error for a sample dag I am trying to write.

My Airflow is of below configuration:-

pip install apache-airflow[crypto,celery,postgres,hive,jdbc,mysql,ssh,docker,hdfs,redis,slack,webhdfs,httplib2]==1.10.12
--constraint /requirements-python3.7.txt

Error:-

```
[2020-12-19 22:41:19,342] {dagbag.py:259} ERROR - Failed to import: /usr/local/airflow/dags/alert_dag.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 256, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/alert_dag.py", line 6, in <module>
    from httplib2 import Http
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'httplib2'
```

Code:-

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from json import dumps
from httplib2 import Http

default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 12, 19,17,0,0),
    'owner': 'Airflow'
}

def on_success(dict):
    print('on_success_call_back function')
    print(dict)


def on_failure(dict):
    print('on_failure_call_back function')
    # """Hangouts Chat incoming webhook quickstart."""
    # url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/XXXX'
    # bot_message = {'text': 'alert_dag Failed'}

    # message_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

    # http_obj = Http()

    # response = http_obj.request(
    #     uri=url,
    #     method='POST',
    #     headers=message_headers,
    #     body=dumps(bot_message),
    # )

#on_success_call_back=on_success
with DAG(dag_id='alert_dag', schedule_interval="*/5 * * * *", default_args=default_args, catchup=True, dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds=25), on_failure_callback=on_failure) as dag:

    # Task 1
    t1 = BashOperator(task_id='t1', bash_command="exit 0")

    # Task 2
    t2 = BashOperator(task_id='t2', bash_command="echo 'second task'")

    t1 >> t2
```

Comment: same issue here, I'm using airflow 1.10.9